# find element with xpath selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@msalmon00/web-scraping-job-postings-from-indeed-96bd588dcb4b) in order to learn how to build a webscraper to get jobs listings. Now I'm trying to follow along with another website. I run into the problem that I don't know how to extract the links of the individual job listings.

When I'm inspecting the page I've found the element I need
[image]

When I copy the xpath and use it in my code I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import selenium 
base_url = "https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl"     
start_url = "https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl/vacature/zoeken?query=&location=&distance=city&limit=100&sort=relevance&filters%5BcareerLevel%5D%5B%5D=Starter&filters%5BeducationLevel%5D%5B%5D=MBO" 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="search-results-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/job/a")

>>NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="search-results-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/job/a
```

Comment: You missed `driver.get(start_url)` before searching for element

Comment: That is in my code. Accidentally deleted it in my snippet here, oops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should be connecting to your website...

Second, you should use `waits` you can read about it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

the code should look something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 


base_url = "https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl"     
start_url = "https://www.nationalevacaturebank.nl/vacature/zoeken?query=&location=&distance=city&limit=100&sort=relevance&filters%5BcareerLevel%5D%5B%5D=Starter&filters%5BeducationLevel%5D%5B%5D=MBO" 
my_xpath = '//*[@id="search-results-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/job/a'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(start_url)  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, my_xpath)))
```

**Edit**

I order to get all the links of the individual job listing you can create a list of the links and append theme:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-results-container"]//article/job/a')))
list_of_links = []
for i in elements:
    list_of_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
    # print(f"link = {i.get_attribute('href')}")
print(list_of_links)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: How do I get all the links? Now I only get one link

Comment: why does `els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(my_xpath)
for e in els:
    print(e)` not work? Because that would give me a loop. Why does your example with EC.element work and not find_elements? I'm trying really hard to understand. Sorry, I'm a noob

Comment: that's fine! the concept it to wait for the element to really be visible or clickable as explained in the selenium site that I have provided above...

Comment: you can loop through the elements! you just have to put them in a variable

Comment: ok, but after the element is visible is it not possible to get all the elements in a list? like find_elements_by_xpath does. I get an error when I use `element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.find_elements_by_xpath(my_xpath))))`

Comment: when you use `EC` you must pass the `By` and the `xpath` or the `ID` in separate statements so what you can do is locate the elements after the `wait`

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by that =( If you have an example I can see what you mean but now I'm kind of confused as to where I can get the elements. Especially, when I use `els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(my_xpath)` after `wait` it doesn't work

Comment: I'd like to show you in your example but is this that site you are using?

Comment: I tried this and it works fine! `all_jobs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-results-container"]')
for i in all_jobs:
    print(i.text)`

Comment: Do you still use `wait`? I don't get anything back when I use that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181163/discussion-between-moshe-slavin-and-lunalight).